Script to submit value from disabled control not working
I've found this cute and simple piece of code here:
Disabled form fields not submitting data
That seems to be working for some people.
I inserted it in my project (ASP.NET Core 8.0 MVC), but it is not working:
@model Profession

<script type="text/javascript">
        @* ********** Script pour inclure dans le formulaire soumis le champ "NoProfession" qui est désactivé ********** *@
        $('form').submit(function(e) {
            $(':disabled').each(function(e) {
                $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
            })
        });
</script>

<form method="post">
    <div class="border p-3 mt-4 row">
        <div class="row pb-2">
            <h2 class="text-primary">MODIFIER UNE PROFESSION</h2>
            <hr />
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3 row p-1" style="width: 15em;">
            <label asp-for="NoProfession"> </label>
            <input asp-for="NoProfession" class="form-control" disabled />
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="mb-3 row p-1">
            <label asp-for="NomProfession"> </label>
            <input asp-for="NomProfession" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="NomProfession" class="text-bg-danger"> </span>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="mb-3 row p-1">
            <label asp-for="Inactif"> </label>
            <input asp-for="Inactif" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox">
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="mb-3 row p-1">
            <label asp-for="RemProfession"> </label>
            <textarea asp-for="RemProfession" class="form-control" rows="5"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6 col-md-3">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control">Modifier</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 col-md-3">
                <a asp-controller="Administrateur" asp-action="Professions" class="btn btn-secondary border form-control">
                    Retour à la liste des professions
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

@section Scripts {
        @* ********** Activation de la validation coté utilisateur ********** *@
        @{
            <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
        }
}


When you include JavaScript directly inside the Razor view, it may not execute as expected if placed outside of @section Scripts, especially in ASP.NET Core projects that rely on a layout page to load JavaScript after the body of the page.
Moving the script into the @section Scripts:
@section Scripts {
    @{
        <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />    
    }

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('form').submit(function (e) {
            $(':disabled').each(function (e) {
                $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
            })
        });
    </script>
}

Reference: Sections

Thanks, works fine
